# Python Converting .csv file with comma delimiter to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So I have tried to fix this problem for quite a while now and did some research on trying to figure out why my code won't work, but I simply can't get the dictionary to print with all the proper key:value pairs I need.

So here's the story. I am reading a .csv file where the first column are text abbreviations and in the second column they are the full english meaning. Now I have tried multiple ways of trying to open this file, read it, and then store it to dictionary we create. My issue is that the file gets read, and when I print the separated pieces (I believe it goes through the whole file, but I don't know since it does get cut off around line 1007, but goes through to 4600. The problem is that when I now want to take all that stuff and put it into key:value pairs inside a dictionary. The only one that gets stored is the very first line in the file.

Here is the code:

```
def createDictionary(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        #line = line.strip()
        data = line.split(',')
        print data
        dic[data[0]] = data[1]
        print dic
```

What I assumed was the issue was:

```
    print dic
```

Since it is printing within the loop, but since it is in the loop it should just print everytime it goes through again and again. I am confused on what I am doing wrong. The other methods I attempted to use were json, but I don't know too much about how to use it, and then I also read up about the csv module, but I don't think our professor wants us to use that so i was hoping for someone to spot my error. Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT**

This is the output of my program

```
going to be late\rg2cu', 'glad to see you\rg2e', 'got to eat\rg2g', 'got to go\rg2g2tb', 'got to go to the bathroom\rg2g2w', 'got to go to work\rg2g4aw', 'got to go for a while\rg2gb', 'got to go bye\rg2gb2wn', 'got to go back to work now\rg2ge', 'got to go eat\rg2gn', 'got to go now\rg2gp', 'got to go pee\rg2gpc', 'got 2 go parents coming\rg2gpp', 'got to go pee pee\rg2gs', 'got to go sorry\rg2k', 'good to know\rg2p', 'got to pee\rg2t2s', 'got to talk to someone\rg4u', 'good for you\rg4y', 'good for you\rg8', 'gate\rg9', 'good night\rga', 'go ahead\rgaalma', 'go away and leave me alone\rgafi', 'get away from it\rgafm', 'Get away from me\rgagp', 'go and get pissed\rgaj'
```

Which goes on for a bit until the end of the file and then after that its supposed to print the entire dictionary in which I get this

```
   {'$$': 'money\r/.'}
```

Along with a

```
none
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the full code:

```
def createDictionary(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        data = line.split(',')
        print data
        dic[data[0]] = data[1]
        print dic

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = createDictionary("textToEnglish.csv")
    print x
```

**EDIT 3**

Here is the file I am trying to make into a dictionary

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqnudQBXpxTGiC9vQEopu1dOciIS

Comment: Can you show us a bit of the output of this?

Comment: Do you mean what you get to see from the terminal when I run the program? If so, I am new to this site still, and don't know how to show it besides taking a screenshot?

Comment: *I believe it goes through the whole file, but I don't know since it does get cut off around line 1007, but goes through to 4600.* Alas, believing is not part of programming, as there is no magic in our work -- does your code work with smaller files, possibly less than 1000 lines? How exactly does the code break?

Comment: @Joseph, re: your first comment, just edit the output into your question, either as code (indent four spaces) or quote (put `>` signs on every line and pray for the best ;) Or just use the buttons on the toolbar.

Comment: Well, when I run the program, I have it print the data piece which is just all of the lines that it is parsing by the comma delimiter. When it runs through the loop I scroll up and noticed that the first piece was not the first line in the file, so I checked and saw that the first line was 1007, and the last line was the final line in the file. I want to believe my code works for more than a thousand lines, but I am beginning to think it may not. Also I don't know if is the terminal just can't handle that many lines at once either.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I just noticed that the print of all the lines does not include the text abbreviations and only the english translation. So its taking in only the second column and not the first column.

Comment: I get to error with current code and posted data. Please incorporate a reproducible example that reproduces your error.

Comment: @Parfait What is the error exactly? I will edit the post with the full code, but I am just curious what the error is.

Comment: Apologies - I meant I get **no** error.

Comment: @Parfait Oh, okay. Well I don't get an error exactly, instead I am not getting the preferred outcome from my code. I need it to take the .csv file and make it into a dictionary, but it is not doing that so I was hoping someone could help with that issue.

Comment: I am not understanding. This above code with data does indeed return a dictionary. What is your desired result? I took your output and took the backslash separator as a comma for the comma-separated data. Maybe my assumption of this data is incorrect. Please post the csv data so we can properly reproduce.

Comment: @Parfait I added the file to the post. Hopefully you will understand what I mean by not producing the dictionary correctly.

Comment: Run the code as best you can, and copy some reasonable, representative amount of the code. In fact, delete or comment out the line that says "print dic" first. Then paste that into your answer. We cannot help until you start giving us something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `return` in your function. Also, you will see the dictionary length is not the same as csv rows due to repeated values in first column of csv. Dictionary keys must be unique, so when a reused key is assigned to a value, the latter value replaces former.

```
def createDictionary(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        #line = line.strip()
        data = line.split(',')
        print(data)
        dic[data[0]] = data[1]
    return dic 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = createDictionary("textToEnglish.csv") 
    print type(x)
    # <class 'dict'>

    print len(x)
    # 4255

for k, v in x.items():
    print(k, v)
```

And try not to `print` dictionary all at once especially with so many values which becomes intense overhead on memory. See how you can iterate through keys and values with `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing wrong with the other solutions presented, you could simplify and greatly escalate your solutions by using python's excellent library pandas.

Pandas is a library for handling data in Python, preferred by many Data Scientists.

Pandas has a simplified CSV interface to read and parse files, that can be used to return a list of dictionaries, each containing a single line of the file. The keys will be the column names, and the values will be the ones in each cell.

In your case:

```
    import pandas

    def createDictionary(filename):
        my_data = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(filename, sep=',', index_col=False)
        list_of_dicts = [item for item in my_data.T.to_dict().values()]
        return list_of_dicts

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = createDictionary("textToEnglish.csv") 
        print type(x)
        # <class 'list'>
        print len(x)
        # 4255
        print type(x[0])
        # <class 'dict'>
```